# KML search not working with Google Maps 7 on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, kml

On my Android devices I can go to maps.google.com in the browser, and I can search for a KML [URL](http://gigapan.com/gigapans/38657.kml) (to pick a random example that comes up via a Google search) and it'll display the results.

If I run the original version of the Google Maps app on my device (a Galaxy S3) which is 6.12.0 and search for the same URL then it also displays the results.

But if I use the latest `7.1.0` version of the `Google Maps` app, and I try to search for the same URL, I just get a toast with `No results for http://gigapan.com/gigapans/38657.kml`. Is there any way to get it to display the results from a KML file in the new v7 app, or is this feature no longer supported? When starting a new Activity with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` is there any way to detect what version of the Google Maps app is installed, and only offer the browser in the case that the v7 Maps app is installed?